# How to use If statement during select from Linq to Datasets

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have this LINQ statement

```
Dim Demo = From d In DBDataTable.AsEnumerable _                 
     Select id = d.Field(Of Integer)("id"), _
            Column = d.Field(Of Object)  (_column2), _
            Col3 = d.Field(Of Object)(_column3), _
            Col4 = IIf(_Col4 <> -1, d.Field(Of Object)(_Col4), Nothing)
```

Is there any way that I can use if/iif within select ?

Comment: You don't typically use if statements inside the select part. Usually, a where clause is sufficient. Can you describe why an 'if' statement is required in the select? I don't understand what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Well, I need to check the Datacol index value which I am calculating dynamically and First I need to check the value if its not -1 then only I need to apply that index value to datatable otherwise it will returns that  column  -1 not found in datasource

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[This is a summary of the discussion in the question comments.]*

Your code won't work since `IIf` always evaluates both the *true* and the *false* part. Thus, evaluating `d.Field(Of Object)(_Col4)` will raise an exception if `_Col4 = -1`.

Instead, use `If(condition, true, false)`, which works like C#'s `condition ? true : false` operator and only evaluates either the *true* or the *false* part, depending on *condition*. So, your code should read:

```
Dim Demo = From d In DBDataTable.AsEnumerable _
           Select id = d.Field(Of Integer)("id"), _
                  Col2 = d.Field(Of Object)(_column2), _
                  Col3 = d.Field(Of Object)(_column3), _
                  Col4 = If(_Col4 <> -1, d.Field(Of Object)(_Col4), Nothing)
```